# What can I do to get my desired output using Seqkit to separates my Fasta files into separate genes?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line

I am trying to separate my Fasta file into  separate genes using this command on my terminal

AB753217|A/African_Stonechat/Vietnam/8/2009|H9N2 |HA|2009-11
AF202232|A/African_starling/England-Q/983/1979|H7N1 |HA|1979
AF149295|A/African_starling/England-Q/983/1979|H7N1 |HA|1979
CY079452|A/American_black_duck/Illinois/08OS2688/2008|H5N2 |HA|2008-10-26
CY097050|A/American_black_duck/Illinois/3854/2009|H11N9 |HA|2009-11-15
CY097534|A/American_black_duck/Illinois/4119/2009|H8N4 |HA|2009-11-29
GU053263|A/American_black_duck/Maryland/415/2001|H7N3 |HA|2001
GU053277|A/American_black_duck/Maryland/424/2001|H7N3 |HA|2001
EU500852|A/American_black_duck/NB/2538/2007|H7N3 |HA|2007

seqkit grep -r -p *HA$ ncbi_fluA_clean.fasta -o HA.fasta #for HA gene

I used this command but got error

zsh: no matches found: *HA$

please what can I do to get my desired output of separating the Fasta file into various gene?
Thank you

Comment: Best to include an OS tag [tag:linux] or [tag:ms-win] to get more viewers to your Question. But you may solve your immediate problem with `seqkit grep -r -p '*HA$' ncbi_fluA_clean.fasta -o HA.fasta` . Note the single quotes (`'`).  I am not familiar with the `seqkit` command, but as your error msg is `zsh: no matches...` That error message is definitely because of lack of single quotes around your search target. Good luck.